# mongodb - nin & regex on an array

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have 2 collections, and I'm trying to get all records from `Coll_A` where a certain field (`Field1`) is not present in `Coll_B`.

The issue I'm running into is that this `Field1` in `Coll_A`, which contains a string value, is padded at the end with white spaces up to a certain length, but this padding is absent in the other collection.

So, for the below query, the `vals` array has records that aren't padded, so when I use the `db.Coll_A.find`, it returns incorrect results.

```
vals = db.Coll_B.find({}, 
                      {"Field1" : 1, _id: 0})
                .map(function(a){
                      return a.Field1;
                    });
db.Coll_A.find({ "Field1": { $nin: vals }});
```

How can I get around this? I looked up using `regex` for ignoring whitespaces, but I'm not sure how that can be used here. Any assistance would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply, modify the return value to an `array` of `regular expressions` and use it in your `$nin` operator.

code:

```
var exp = db.Coll_B.find({}, {"Field1" : 1, _id: 0}).map(function(a){
                                 return new RegExp(a.Field1+"\\s*$");
                             });
db.coll_A.find({"Field1":{$nin:exp}});
```

You cannot use [`$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/regex/) operator inside the [`$nin`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/nin/) or `$in` operators.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware I could modify the return to an array of regex. This worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to fix inconsistent data in the collection. Update all the records with trimming white space around the field.

If for some reason you can't or don't want to do it, then you can use `forEach` and manually do the checking

```
var results = [];
db.Coll_A.find({}).forEach(function(row){
   if(row.Field1.trim().indexOf(vals) === -1){
     results.push(row);
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using the suggestion below, but it's nice to have such options for future use,